On the Oba Prophecy Included in Yves Dupont's, "Catholic Prophecy"
On p. 115 of Catholic Prophecy by Yves Dupont, we find:

Oba Prophecy. "It will come when the Church authorities issue directives to promote a new cult, when priests are forbidden to celebrate in any other, when the higher positions in the Church are given to perjurers and hypocrites, when only the renegades are admitted to occupy those positions."

QUESTION: Where may I find a reference for this "Oba Prophecy"? The above book was published in 1970.
Thank you.
